# IRON Pdf issue in PDFDocument

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, ironpdf

I am facing issue in second line of below code for some PDFs not all...
Where code is getting stuck on 2nd line and not throwing any error and not coming out of that line. Below att variable is a .pdf file. Even if there is any way so that it throws an error and come out of the program.Any solution is much appreciated

```c#
IronPdf.PdfDocument pdfAtt = null;

pdfAtt = new IronPdf.PdfDocument(Path.Combine(tempFolderPath + att.FileName));
```

Comment: Hello Vivek, Michael from Iron Software here,

I've tried that code and it has worked find for me without getting stuck. Would you mind sharing the PDF file that is causing this?

Comment: Thanks Michael for looking into this...that code is working fine for me also but for few PDFs program is getting stuck on that line... Can't share those PDFs due to DPA.  As per the official reply this error is changed to warning in version 2022.9.9056 that's why I think it's creating issue and not coming out of the program...

Comment: Error while copying bookmarks (Document annotations not initialized).                                But we are getting this issue in version 2021.1.29...when updating to latest version getting some other wierd output like multiple tiffs generated for 1 pdf and that is known bug of iron pdf latest version...

Comment: Please send an email with your PDF attached to developers@ironsoftware.com so our developers can take a look at why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks mate...I can't send that pdf as that contains the user data. Will try with dummy pdf and if able to reproduce then will send it across.

Comment: Hi Vivek, Darren from Iron Software. It's been identified as a new bug, so will be fixed in the next release.